# Allocate a node pointers in a tree in C++

Tags: c++, variables, tree

The question can be summarized to :
How to properly handle pointers initialization in a recursive function ?

I guess this question is fairly easy but i still can't figure out how to solve it.

I have a tree structure defined as follow :

```
class SplitNode{

public:
    Data d;
    SplitNodeParam snp;
    SplitNode* left_; //will stay uninitialized
    SplitNode* right_;}
```

I build a tree from its root with the following recursive function:

```
void buildTree(SplitNode* n){
    findBestSplit(n);
    buildTree(n->left);
    buildTree(n->right); //forget that the tree growing doesnt stop
}
```

I take a node and its data and make a split of the datas depending on a function.
And i would like to assign the current node left and right children as follow.

```
void findBestSplit(SplitNode* n){

    //Do stuff with data and parameters

    SplitNodeParam left_parameter(/*Some parameters*/);
    *(n->left)=SplitNode(left_parameter); 

    SplitNodeParam right_parameter(/*Some parameters*/);
    *(n->right)=SplitNode(right_parameter);

}
```

Big problem seems that i want to assign a null pointer SplitNode to a local variable and hope to get it back later which is pretty much impossible.

I saw some example in C to do something similar (with malloc) but i would like to have how this would be neatly done in C++

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want something more like `n->left = new SplitNode(left_parameter)`.  What you have now is copying a temporary into a dereferenced nullptr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to assign `n->left` to a local variable as you're doing here. I'm assuming you haven't allocated any memory for these split nodes at this point in `findBestSplit`.

Instead, you'll have to manage memory by saying `n->left = new SplitNode(left_parameter)` and then cleaning up the allocated  memory later with a corresponding `delete` call. Same goes for `n->right`.

You'll probably end up having a `deleteTree` function that takes a root node. That root node will recursively call `deleteTree` on its children until it gets to a leaf node. At a leaf node, the node will delete itself and then return. This way you don't lose track of all of the tree leaves and you can properly release all of the memory.